# How to set software restriction policies programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, group-policy

I would like to add software restriction policies programmatically using c#.
For example: Add and additional rule to disallows paint.exe to run.

Unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea how I could achieve this in c#

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [RSoP WMI classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375082%28VS.85%29.aspx) with [WMICodeCreator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) to update the group policy.

you could also exec gpupdate.exe directly or tweak the registry.

these xml policies can be useful:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

IGroupPolicyObject - Windows API to create/update policies programmatically.

I would recommend you to go through this links, they will explain in deep about accessing Group Policies programmatically.

[Working with Group Policy Objects Programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2009/07/23/working-with-group-policy-objects-programmatically-simple-c-example-illustrating-how-to-modify-a-registry-based-policy.aspx)

[Programmatically updating local policy in Windows](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows/)

If you have any other query, do ask.

Answer (score 0):

The function requires 3 pieces of information:

- ADsPath to the GPO object to modify A mode control values, 0=Not
- Configured, 1=Enabled, 2=Disabled The actual value to write in the
- Key that represents the mode control value.